# I am suffering from Bigquery with StandardSQL joining method

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to use the following two tables (POS and STAY) with Bigquery's StandardSQL to produce the following results. However, the join part of the third line is not successful. Please tell me a nice way.

```
    dt  rm  total   s_dt    s_rm    s_rank
1   1   r1  100 1   r1  A
2   2   r1  100 2   r1  B
3   3   r1  100 2   r1  B

##dt = date type
```

This is the query I wrote.

```
WITH POS AS(
  select 1 as dt,"r1" as rm,100 as total
  UNION ALL 
  select 2 as dt,"r1" as rm,100 as total
  UNION ALL 
  select 3 as dt,"r1" as rm,100 as total
),
STAY AS(
  select 1 as dt,"r1" as rm,"A" as rank
  UNION ALL 
  select 2 as dt,"r1" as rm,"B" as rank
)
SELECT
  p.*,
  s.dt as s_dt,
  s.rm as s_rm,
  s.rank as s_rank
FROM
  POS as p
LEFT JOIN
  STAY as s
ON
  p.dt = s.dt
  and
  p.rm = s.rm
```

---

This is the result.

```
    dt  rm  total   s_dt    s_rm    s_rank
1   1   r1  100 1   r1  A
2   2   r1  100 2   r1  B
3   3   r1  100 null    null    null
```

Comment: Can you clarify why you expect the values from second table in row 3 of the result. What is the logic behind it?

Comment: I analyzed POS data in connection with accommodation data. The last purchase is a purchase after the last staying day, but I want to put it in the last staying day.

Answer (score 0):

I did it

```
WITH POS AS(
  select 1 as dt,"r1" as rm,100 as total
  UNION ALL 
  select 2 as dt,"r1" as rm,100 as total
  UNION ALL 
  select 3 as dt,"r1" as rm,100 as total

),
STAY AS(
  select 1 as dt,"r1" as rm,"A" as rank
  UNION ALL 
  select 2 as dt,"r1" as rm,"B" as rank
),
POS_STAY as(
SELECT
  p.*,
  s.dt as s_dt,
  s.rm as s_rm,
  s.rank as s_rank,
  if(p.dt = s.dt,1,0) as flag,
  max(if(p.dt = s.dt,1,0)) over (PARTITION BY p.dt) as dt_flag,
  max(s.dt) over (PARTITION BY p.dt) as max_s_dt_flag  
FROM
  POS as p
CROSS JOIN
  STAY as s
)
select
  *
from
  POS_STAY
WHERE
  flag = 1 or (dt_flag = 0 and s_dt = max_s_dt_flag)
```

This is the result.

```
    dt  rm  total   s_dt    s_rm    s_rank  flag    dt_flag max_s_dt_flag
1   1   r1  100 1   r1  A   1   1   2
2   2   r1  100 2   r1  B   1   1   2
3   3   r1  100 2   r1  B   0   0   2
```